# Five people taking $20\%$ of coins - word problem

Tags: percentages, word-problem, natural-numbers

There are $x>0$ coins in a pile and $5$ people who take from the pile according to the following rule:  The first person takes $20$% of coins, the second takes $20$% of the remaining coins, the third takes $20$% of remaining coins, and so on. If there are any coins left after all the $5$ people take coins, the remaining coins are divided equally among the five people. Note that it's impossible to split coins.

What is the minimum value of $x$ so that everyone takes a coin without violating rules?

Someone may ask what's my attempt, but I wasn't able to solve this and asking for the correct solution.

Comment: I'm assuming that $x$ must be chosen such that at each turn, each person takes $1/5$ of the coins.  If so, try solving this problem for two people.  The first person takes $x/5$, leaving $4x/5$.  The second person takes a fifth of *that*, or $4x/25$, leaving $16x/25$.  Do you see a pattern?  Now that $16x/25$ would have to be an integer, and moreover it must be an even integer, since this remainder must now be divided amongst the two people.  Now see if you can extend this to five people.

Comment: Yes, I did like that and end up with answer $3125$, which is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, that answer is incorrect.  I can't tell for sure, but you may have forgotten the condition that the remaining coins all be evenly divisible amongst the five people.

Comment: $3125$ is wrong because the leftover amount is $\left(\frac 45\right)^5\times 3125=4^5$ which is not divisible by $5$.  You need one extra factor of $5$ to handle the remainder.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you confirm the answer is $15625$? Thanks.

Comment: That's the answer I see, $5^6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the fifth person takes a coin, there must be a nonzero remaining number of coins, since they only took 20% of the coins that were there and it is impossible to split coins. Since the remaining coins have to be split evenly among all 5 people, the remaining number of coins must be $5k$ for some positive whole number $k > 0$.

Now we work backwards. Since each person took 20% of the remainder, each person must have multiplied the amount of coins they started with by $4/5$. Therefore, we must multiply by $5/4$ at each turn:

- Before 5th person: $5/4 * 5k = 25k/4$
- Before 4th person: $5/4 * 25k/4 = 125k/16$
- Before 3rd person: $5/4 * 125k/16 = 625k/64$
- Before 2nd person: $5/4 * 625k/64 = 3125k/256$
- Before 1st person: $5/4 * 3125k/256 = 15625k/1024$

So $k$ must be divisible by $1024$, and the smallest possible such value of $k$ is obviously $1024$. Therefore there were $15625(1024)/1024 = 15625$ coins originally. The full sequence goes:

- Start: 15625
- First person takes 20%: 12500
- Second person takes 20%: 10000
- Third person takes 20%: 8000
- Fourth person takes 20%: 6400
- Fifth person takes 20%: 5120
- Divide by 5: 1024 each

At the end, the distribution of wealth is $$[3125, 2500, 2000, 1600, 1280] + [1024, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024] = [4149, 3524, 3024, 2624, 2304],$$ where the number in position $i$ is the wealth of person $i$ for $i = 1$ through $5$.